# ERROR: ORA-02266: unique/primary keys even after disable foreign keys

Tags: oracle, truncate

I try to truncate a table in my db using `TRUNCATE table APPROVAL;` but an error

`ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys` pop up. But, I already disable the foreign key. [Foreign key status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T7GO.png). If possible I don't want to use `CASCADE`. Is there anything I missing?

Comment: looks like you disabled the wrong foreign key, it references USER_ACTION_PK, not APPROVAL_PK

Comment: The foreign key is ```APPROVALA_ACTION_ID_FK``` not ```USER_ACTION_PK```.

Comment: Yes, and according to your image APPROVALA_ACTION_ID_FK references USER_ACTION_PK, you have to disable the foreign keys that references APPROVAL, not the foreign keys in APPROVAL